# How to delete many of data in "Realtime Database"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete all data in "Realtime Database", without increasing "Usage Load" in "Realtime Database".

any idea for deleting that data?
is 420,000+ data in realtime database

Here is image

If you can help me, its very usefull..

[image: Image Total Data]

[Image Usage Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOrMZ.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is support for deleting large nodes built into the Firebase CLI these days as explained in this blog [How to Perform Large Deletes in the Realtime Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/large-deletes-in-realtime-database.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20delete,performs%20a%20chunked%20delete%20efficiently.&text=Keep%20in%20mind%20that%20in,break%20it%20down%20into%20chunks.):

> If you want to delete a large node, the new recommended approach is to use the [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) (> v6.4.0). The CLI automatically detects a large node and performs a chunked delete efficiently.
>
> `$ firebase database:remove /path/to/delete`

---

My initial write-up is below.   I'm pretty sure the CLI mentioned above implements precisely this approach, so that's likely a faster way to accomplish this, but I'm still leaving this explanation as it may be useful as background.

Deleting data is a write operation, so it's by definition going to put load on the database. Deleting a lot of data causes a lot of load, either as a spike in a short period or (if you spread it out) as a lifted load for a longer period. Spreading the load out is the best way to minimize impact for your regular users.

The best way to delete a long, flat list of keys (as you seem to have) is to:

1. Get a list of that keys, either from a backup of your database (which happens out of band), or by using the `shallow` parameter on the REST API.
2. Delete the data in reasonable batches, where reasonable depends on the amount of data you store per key. If each key is just a few properties, you could start deleting 100 keys per batch, and check how that impacts the load to determine if you can ramp up to more keys per batch.